# Is it possible to use aliases in the projection part of SELECT statement?

Tags: mysql

Consider the following query:

```
SELECT SUM(A) as S1, SUM(B) as S2, S1+S2 AS S3 FROM mytable
```

It results in the following error:

`[1054] Unknown column 'S1' in 'field list'`

So how is it possible to do such thing?

P.S: I know that this is indirectly possible with nested queries. I'm looking for a clean solution.

Answer (score 1):

No, you need to use a subquery:

```
SELECT s1, s2, s1+s2 AS s3
FROM (SELECT SUM(a) AS s1, SUM(b) AS s2
      FROM mytable) AS subquery
```

I posted this answer before the question was edited to say that he knew about using a subquery.